# Zephyr nrf52840DK LED GPIO question

Tags: nordic

I have a nordic nrf52840dk board. Using the Zephyr RTOS. I can see the following device tree source

```c
leds {
    compatible = "gpio-leds";
    led0: led_0 {
        gpios = <&gpio0 13 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        label = "Green LED 0";
    };
    ...
}

aliases {
    led0 = &led0;
    ...
}
```

The GPIO is set to `GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW` mode.

But when I test the following led code which is slightly modified from the example `blinky`

```c
#define SLEEP_TIME_MS  5000
#define LED0_NODE      DT_ALIAS(led0)

static const struct gpio_dt_spec led = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(LED0_NODE, gpios);

void main(void)
{
    int ret;

    if (!device_is_ready(led.port)) {
        return;
    }

    ret = gpio_pin_configure_dt(&led, GPIO_OUTPUT_ACTIVE);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return;
    }
    printk("gpio is ready, let's start ... ");
    int value = 0;
    while (1) {
        value = (value == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        ret = gpio_pin_set_dt(&led, value);
        
        printk("set pin result: %d, value: %d\n", ret, value);
        if (ret < 0) {
            return;
        }
        k_msleep(SLEEP_TIME_MS);
    }
}
```

The result is: when the `value` is 1 the `led0` on the board is on, and the LED is off when the value is set to 0. I am a bit confused. Because I think the `GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW` means when the pin is set to high the output is in a high-z (high impedance) state, which should turn the led off. But the result is the opposite. Am I missing something or my understanding of active low is incorrect?

Comment: How is the LED connected to the pin (anode/cathode)?

Comment: @Seir Good question, how do I find out?

Comment: I see you resolved your issue, so this question isn't as relevant anymore. The reason I was asking: If the cathode is connected to your pin and the anode to V+, the LED would light up when you pull the pin LOW. And if the cathode is connected to your pin and the cathode to GND, the LED would light up when you pull the pin HIGH. (don't forget the current limiting resistor)

Comment: @Seir thanks for your answer,  and your question really enlightened me to do the test to solve the puzzle. So thanks for your question as well :)

Comment: Typo: And if the *anode* is connected to your pin and the cathode to GND, the LED would light up when you pull the pin HIGH.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the on board `led0` is "connected" to the `gpio0 13`(p0.13) but not controlled by the same GPIO. If I build a circuit with a resistor and another LED (led1) on a breadboard using `p0.13` as positive. I can see when the led1 is on while the led0 is off. It all makes sense now.